# i can not show the images in html

Tags: python, html

I´m new in python and django.
My code is below and the problem is that the images do not appear.
I include in the teste.html this tag but it didn´t work src="./assets/images/3ed274bc061c771ef0b153111a6fe932_logocartorio.png"

**My path is:**

```
BCcartorio 
   bccartorio
      settings
      urls
   iddigital
      views
      urls
   templates      
      iddigital
         teste.html
         assets
            css
            images
            js
```

**My iddigital.views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse
def home(request):
     return (render(request, "iddigital/teste.html"))
```

**My teste.html:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>teste</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" name="button">login</button>

    <div class="bd-vertical-align-wrapper">
        <img class="bd-imagelink-1 bd-own-margins bd-imagestyles   "  src="./assets/images/3ed274bc061c771ef0b153111a6fe932_logocartorio.png">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the path to the image correct? Do you get a 404 error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good practice to hard-code the URL of an image as this can cause many unexpected problems(e.g. paths mixup). In order to avoid this `Django` provides a hassle-free way to manage and serve your static files easily.

First you have to include the `django.contrib.staticfiles` app in your `INSTALLED_APPS` and then define in your `settings` file the `STATIC_URL` which will serve as the base path that'll be used by `Django` to find your static files in a template. It is a good practice to have a separate `static` folder that will contain the `assets` folder which -in turn- will contain your `css`, `js`, `images` etc sub-folders.

So I'd take the `assets` folder from that path and put move it in a `static` folder that would be in the same level as the `iddigital` and `templates` ones. In that case your `STATIC_URL`  variable would be equal to `'/static/`.

Now in the `teste.html` template you can load your static folder by adding `{% load static %}` at the top of your file. Your images can now be called as simple as this: `<img src="{% static "assets/images/logocartorio.png" %}" class="bd-imagelink-1 bd-own-margins bd-imagestyles"/>`

More info on the above can be found at the excellent `Django`[documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/).

Comment: Thanks. I did everythind you wrote but it didn´t work. I don´t know how to solve this problem.

Comment: That's really strange. Have you followed the steps as outlined in the official link of `django` documentation that I posted above?

Comment: Hi! i followed all the steps. I´ve already creaty a new project. 2 images are showed on the screen but the others didn´t. I don´t know why.

Comment: If two of them are displayed on screen and the others aren't then it must have been an error on your end. Are all images in the same folder? Have you checked for any typing errors?

Comment: Yes, all the images are in the same folder. The message is:   Request URL:http://localhost:8000/static/iddigital/assets/js/jquery.js%3F1.0.670 and Status Code:404 Not Found. But exist the file "jquery.js" in this folder. I don´t understand "%3F1.0.670".

Comment: If you followed all the steps then `assets` should be inside the `static` folder. From the error it seems that the `assets` folder is in the `iddigital` folder though.

Comment: So, right i have inside iddigital 2 folders called: static and templates. Inside templates i have the folder iddigital and inside it i have iddigital.html. Inside folder static i have the folder iddigital and inside it i have assets and inside it i have 3 folders called css, images and js. The iddigital views is like this -> def home(request):    return(render(request,"iddigital/iddigital.html")). STATIC_URL = '/static/'. 'django.contrib.staticfiles' is in INSTALLED_APPS. And teste.html is big because before i made only a test.

Comment: You don't need an `iddigital` folder inside your `templates` one. Also, apart from `STATIC_URL = '/static/'` you should also have `STATICFILES_DIR = [ os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static') ]` in your `settings.py` file. After that you can: `return render(request,"iddigital.html")`

Comment: NIce! You can mark my answer as correct if it helped you :)

Comment: Hi! ok, but how can i do that ?

Comment: By clicking on the check mark next to it. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you!